# Using Jscript Add ONLY the integers in a 2D array. Then working out the difference between each month of the same array to get the average difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Javavscript help (array at bottom)
I have a 2D array which holds a date of month in one column (a string) and an integer next to it i.e. array= ['Oct 2020' , 23456], ['Nov 2020' , 34567], ['Dec 2020' , -4567]...etc I have to work out:

- total amount of months in this array (which I've managed),
- the total of all the profit/loss form the integers (which I've managed alt methods welcome it'll help me learn more),
- the average difference of profit/loss between each month's by calculating the difference between each month first then adding and dividing by total number of months,
- the month with the biggest profit in the array
- the month with biggest lost in the array.

I'm able to provide the code. I think I understand how to do this in a 1D array but with a 2D array the results didn't work. Please could I have some help and a walk through of your answer. I don't mind how its worked out but if you could have an example with the reduce function in your answer and an answer without that would be great if not no problem.

```
var finances = [
['Jan-2010', 867884],
['Feb-2010', 984655],
['Mar-2010', 322013],
['Apr-2010', -69417],
['May-2010', 310503],
['Jun-2010', 522857],
['Jul-2010', 1033096],
['Aug-2010', 604885],
['Sep-2010', -216386],
['Oct-2010', 477532],
['Nov-2010', 893810],
['Dec-2010', -80353],
['Jan-2011', 779806],
['Feb-2011', -335203],
['Mar-2011', 697845],
['Apr-2011', 793163],
['May-2011', 485070],
['Jun-2011', 584122],
['Jul-2011', 62729],
['Aug-2011', 668179],
['Sep-2011', 899906],
['Oct-2011', 834719],
['Nov-2011', 132003],
['Dec-2011', 309978],
['Jan-2012', -755566],
['Feb-2012', 1170593],
['Mar-2012', 252788],
['Apr-2012', 1151518],
['May-2012', 817256],
['Jun-2012', 570757],
['Jul-2012', 506702],
['Aug-2012', -1022534],
['Sep-2012', 475062],
['Oct-2012', 779976],
['Nov-2012', 144175],
['Dec-2012', 542494],
['Jan-2013', 359333],
['Feb-2013', 321469],
['Mar-2013', 67780],
['Apr-2013', 471435],
['May-2013', 565603],
['Jun-2013', 872480],
['Jul-2013', 789480],
['Aug-2013', 999942],
['Sep-2013', -1196225],
['Oct-2013', 268997],
['Nov-2013', -687986],
['Dec-2013', 1150461],
['Jan-2014', 682458],
['Feb-2014', 617856],
['Mar-2014', 824098],
['Apr-2014', 581943],
['May-2014', 132864],
['Jun-2014', 448062],
['Jul-2014', 689161],
['Aug-2014', 800701],
['Sep-2014', 1166643],
['Oct-2014', 947333],
['Nov-2014', 578668],
['Dec-2014', 988505],
['Jan-2015', 1139715],
['Feb-2015', 1029471],
['Mar-2015', 687533],
['Apr-2015', -524626],
['May-2015', 158620],
['Jun-2015', 87795],
['Jul-2015', 423389],
['Aug-2015', 840723],
['Sep-2015', 568529],
['Oct-2015', 332067],
['Nov-2015', 989499],
['Dec-2015', 778237],
['Jan-2016', 650000],
['Feb-2016', -1100387],
['Mar-2016', -174946],
['Apr-2016', 757143],
['May-2016', 445709],
['Jun-2016', 712961],
['Jul-2016', -1163797],
['Aug-2016', 569899],
['Sep-2016', 768450],
['Oct-2016', 102685],
['Nov-2016', 795914],
['Dec-2016', 60988],
['Jan-2017', 138230],
['Feb-2017', 671099]
];
```

code for how many months:

```
let monthsTotal = finances.length;

console.log("Total months: ", monthsTotal);
```

my first attempt to try and find the total profits/losses (i.e. sum of all integers). It just printed out the array in a messy form

```
const netTotal =finances.reduce((sum, curVal) => sum + curVal); 

console.log("Total Profits/Loses: ", netTotal);
```

my second attempt actually works to find the sum which i have called netTotal

```
let netTotal = finances.map(function(v) { return v[1] })         // second value of each
     .reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b });  // sum
     console.log('Total:', netTotal)
```

so just the the last 3 bullet points technically

Answer (score 0):

In the `netTotal` calculation, we don't need the extra trip through the array to get the integer value. Just pull it out with `[1]` as you go:

```
let netTotal = finances.reduce((a,b) => a + b[1]);
```

Getting the differences between months is simple if you handle the special case of the first month not having a prior month to compare to.

```
let diffs = finances.map((el, index) => {
  // on the first one, assume the prior value is 0
  let priorValue = index === 0 ? 0 : finances[index-1][1];  // edit
  return el[1] - priorValue;
})
let totalDiffs = diffs.reduce((a,b) => a + b);   // simple sum
let averageDiffs = totalDiffs / finances.length
```

Max and min are a little extra work because the calculation should track the months also. Here's a way to do it where the max/min thing being tracked is the nested array itself.

```
let maxArr = ['', -Number.MAX_VALUE]  // everything is bigger than this
let minArr = ['', Number.MAX_VALUE]   // everything is smaller than this

for (let i=0; i<finances.length; i++) {
  let arr = finances[i];
  if (arr[1] > maxArr[1]) maxArr = arr;
  if (arr[1] < minArr[1]) minArr = arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @danh ! If you don't mind me asking do you have any good websites/videos/tutorials/tips for javascript it seems like there's a lot of functions and other things you can do with it that I don't know or understand yet

Comment: @mike12345 - the best reference that I know about is mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). As for intro material, I haven't used it, but mdn also offers it, starting here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Comment: Hi @danh I tried implementing the Js above and they all work except for the second one. Just to check is it possible that the extra loop around is needed?

Comment: @mike12345 - my bad, I repeated the OP problem of not dereferencing the array at index 1 for the calculation. Fixed in an edit (and marked the edit with a comment)